# Mesh doesnt follow my bones

Tags: rigging

i am a bloody beginner.
I want my mesh to follow my rig-bone.
Instead when rotating it, my mesh (GREEN) stay theys and deforms itself like shi***t

My bone ( LIGHT BROWN) is up as you can see in the picture. But the mesh does whatever it wants.

I  think it must be easy. So please tell me whats up :D

here should be  the link to the *.blend:

pasteall.org/blend/9aefeb4803814b7d83f467d972c5bd91

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Make sure the vertex groups in your mesh match the name of the bones that you want to use to deform the mesh. then check your weight paint, are multiple vertex groups sharing the same weight? are the bones you want to use to deform weighted properly? are the bones you want to use to deform the mesh added in as vertex groups? probably they are missing

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/9aefeb4803814b7d83f467d972c5bd91

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reason why you don't join all the objects and also why they are so high-poly? You could reduce the number of faces and give them a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. But first thing apply the scale and rotation of both the objects and armature, then, as it will invert the normals, go in *Edit* mode for each of them and recalculate the normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. Then parent each object *With Automatic Weights* and it should work fine.

Comment: I will  try :P  It already tried hard. But Tomorrow I will  do my next picture and so my next try :D Thank you for the good tips !!!!!